# How to skip updating timestamps in subdocuments using Mongoose Model.bulkWrite() updateMany operation

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Given a MongoDB collection with following structure:

```
const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
   category: { type: String, required: true },
   title: { type: String, required: true },
   content: { type: String, required: true },
   isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false}
}, { timestamps: true })

const User = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: { type: String, required: true },
   posts: { type: [Post] },
   isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false}
}, { timestamps: true })
```

#### Input

```json
{
    "username": "Tom",
    "posts": [
        {
            "category": "political",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "content": "Content 1",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-06-01T16:00:00:00+0000"),
            "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-02T16:00:00:00+0000")
        },
        {
            "category": "science",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "content": "Content 2",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-06-01T16:00:00:00+0000"),
            "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-03T16:00:00:00+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-06-01T16:00:00:00+0000"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-01T16:00:00:00+0000")
}
```

where `User.posts` is an array of subdocuments with `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes.

How can I update fields in `Post` without updating the its timestamps using `.bulkWrite()` with `updateMany` operation?

I have tried the following operation, but it doesn't work. The operation still updating subdocuments' timestamps even though the `timestamps` option is set to false.

```
/**
 * Find all posts with category === 'political' and update `isDeleted` to true. 
 * Operation didn't update parent document timestamps but still updating timestamps in `posts` 
 */
User.bulkWrite([
   {
      updateMany: {
        filter: {
           isDeleted: false,
        },
        update: {
          $set: {
            'posts.$[post].isDeleted': true,
          }
        },
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            'post.category': { $eq: 'political' },
          },
        ],
        upsert: false,
        timestamps: false 
      },
   }
])
```

#### Output

```json
{
    "username": "Tom",
    "posts": [
        {
            "category": "political",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "content": "Content 1",
            "isDeleted": true, // successfully updated to true
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-07-13T16:00:00:00+0000"), // this updatedAt should not be updated
            "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-02T16:00:00:00+0000")
        },
        {
            "category": "science",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "content": "Content 2",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-03T16:00:00:00+0000"),
            "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-03T16:00:00:00+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-06-01T16:00:00:00+0000"), // 'timestamps: false' works on parent document only
    "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-01T16:00:00:00+0000")
}
```